# Como decrementar, tirando só um numero do outro valor?

Tags: c

No valor final era pra ter o total das notas maiores que 7, outra condição seria que o usuário tem que digitar um numero entre 0 e 10, ai todo numero fora disso daria "mensagem invalida", e teria o decremento dela, assim por exemplo se o usuário digitasse: 11, 9 e 8; ao invés de aparecer no total 3 notas > 7, só iria aparecer 2... **Mas não estou conseguindo fazer, então se alguém souber como resolver, ou outra forma de fazer isso, fala ai nos coments...** Obrigado desde já.

```html
#include <stdio.h> 

int main () { 
    int aluno, i, alunosComNotaMaiorQueSete = 0;
    float nota;

    printf("Quantos alunos fizeram a prova? ");
    scanf("%d", &aluno);

    for(i = 0; i < aluno; i++) { 
   
        printf("Digite a nota do aluno %d:\n", i);
        scanf("%f", &nota);

    if (nota<0 || nota>10)
   { 
        printf("\n Nota Invalida\n");
        alunosComNotaMaiorQueSete--;
   }else if(nota>7 && nota<=10) 
   {
        alunosComNotaMaiorQueSete++;
   }
    }     
    printf("Alunos com nota > 7: %d\n", alunosComNotaMaiorQueSete);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O emulador de código do StackOverFlow é para Javascript, HTML ou CSS, e não para C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa de decrementar só soma se a nota for maior. E também não precisa de dizer que a nota < 10 no else if pois só irá passar para o else if se a condiçao do primeiro if for verdadeira.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main () { 
int aluno, i, alunosComNotaMaiorQueSete = 0;
float nota;

printf("Quantos alunos fizeram a prova? ");
scanf("%d", &aluno);

for(i = 0; i < aluno; i++) { 

    printf("Digite a nota do aluno %d:\n", i);
    scanf("%f", &nota);

    if (nota<0 || nota>10)
    { 
        printf("\n Nota Invalida\n");
        //codigo antigo que nao é preciso: 
        //alunosComNotaMaiorQueSete--;
    }
    else if(nota>7 /*&& nota<=10*/) 
    {
        alunosComNotaMaiorQueSete++;
    }
}        
    printf("Alunos com nota > 7: %d\n", alunosComNotaMaiorQueSete);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: obrigado, valeu ai...